# PyEphem/GDAL finding angle and elevation at a specific range for a specific projection

Tags: gdal, pyephem

I'm working to create a, for example, 5000meter line between an observation point with an elevation to a point directly in the path between the observer and the observed body.

In my case the Sun for now.

I cannot find a preexisting method of finding slope between two points on an ellipsoid to begin with.

A method to find the angle from north and slope in a global ellipsoid projection like WGS94 Mercator from any of the results or transformations that PyEphem offers would get me going really quickly.